# UIScrollView (containing number of UITextFields) is bouncing up and down while switching from predictive keyboard to simple keyboard (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield, autolayout

I am trying to handle the keyboard appearance on the screen and moving the UIScrollView (**tfScroll**) to make my all UITextFields (**tf1, tf2, tf3, tf4, tf5, tf6, tf7**) visible above the keyboard.

- I have added the Keyboard notifications
  (**UIKeyboardWillShowNotification**, **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification**) in
  viewWillAppear method.
- I made **'correction'** option of textfields tf1, tf3, tf5, tf7
  **YES**, and rest of the textfields to **NO** i.e. keyboards with 'YES' to correction option will have **predictive bar** and others with 'NO' to correction option will not have **predictive bar**.
- ScrollView is scrolling very fine and all textfields are visible
  except one issue that, when **predictive bar** of the keyboard
  **appears** or **vanish**, the scrollview bounces to the top and then comes to it's right position, which gives weird look.
- But if I switch off/on the predictive bar of keyboard **for all the textfields**, then
  scrollview scrolls smoothly.
- Please suggest some way to handle the rough scrolling in case of
  switching from **simple keyboard** to **perdictive_bar keyboard**.
- Here is the code that I have implemented to do the above process:

## pragma mark - Keyboard Notification

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *) noti
{
    NSDictionary *info = [noti userInfo];
    
    
    float kbOffset = [[[noti userInfo] valueForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue].origin.y;
    
    
    CGSize keyboardSize = [info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]CGRectValue].size;
    
    
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
    
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    

    
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tfScroll.contentInset.top, 0, keyboardSize.height+10.0, 0);
    
    
    tfScroll.contentInset = insets;
    
    tfScroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
    
    
    float tfOffset ;
    
    if (tf1.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y + tf1.frame.origin.y + tf1.frame.size.height ;
    }
    
    else if (tf2.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y +  tf2.frame.origin.y + tf2.frame.size.height ;
    }
    
    else if (tf3.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y +  tf3.frame.origin.y + tf3.frame.size.height ;
    }

    else if (tf4.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y + tf4.frame.origin.y + tf4.frame.size.height ;
    }

    else if (tf5.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y + tf5.frame.origin.y + tf5.frame.size.height ;
    }

    else if (tf6.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y + tf6.frame.origin.y + tf6.frame.size.height ;
    }

    else if (tf7.isEditing)
    {
        tfOffset = tfScroll.frame.origin.y + tf7.frame.origin.y + tf7.frame.size.height ;
    }

    
    if ((kbOffset - tfOffset) < 0)
    {
        CGFloat y = (kbOffset - tfOffset);
        
        tfScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(tfScroll.frame.origin.x, y);
    }

    
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification *) noti
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tfScroll.contentInset.top, 0, 0, 0);
    
    
    tfScroll.contentInset = insets;
    
    tfScroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;

    tfScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(tfScroll.frame.origin.x, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in my code. It was silly mistake though. When I was changing the 'content offset' of UIScrollView to pull the hidden UITextFields above the keyboard in 'keyboardWillShow' method, I was assigning negative 'y-axis' to content offset, which causes bounces in my scrollview (as difference of (kbOffset - tfOffset) is negative).

So I made a little change in above code, provide +ve y-axis displacement to Scrollview, and starts running fine.

```
 if ((kbOffset - tfOffset) < 0)
{
    CGFloat y = (tfOffset - kbOffset);

    tfScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(tfScroll.frame.origin.x, y);
}
```